# Error when trying to increase java heap size

Tags: java, size, heap-memory

For a minecraft server I'm trying to run the server with more than the standard 512MB RAM. This used to work for me but when I recently installed the server again it stopped working. I use the following command line to run the server:

```
java -Xms1024M -Xmx2048M -jar TekkitLite.jar 
pause
```

But when I run this script I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\...\server>java -Xms1024M -Xmx2048M -jar TekkitLite.jar
```

Picked `up_JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M`
Error occured during initialization of VM
Incompatible minimum and maximum heap sizes specified

It seems to me it just doesn't pick up the Xmx argument or something, and I haven't found a solution to fix it anywhere.

My system:

- OS: Windows 7 64bit
- Java: java7u45(64bit)
- RAM: 8G

If anyone has a solution, that would be awesome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have `-Xmx512M` set in the environment variable `_JAVA_OPTIONS`. Clear that and try again.

In Windows 7, this is done like this:

1. Right-click Computer from the Start menu and choose Properties
2. Click Advanced system settings > Advanced tab
3. Click on Environment Variables, find _JAVA_OPTIONS, and select it.
4. Click Delete
5. Click OK, and you're done!

Comment: thanks for the fast response :) however, i'm totally new to doing things like this, could you explain to me how i can change that variable? :)

Comment: thanks :) indeed, i found the variable and deleted it, running server with 3G ram now:D thanks for the help!